# (JavaScript) The only output I get back is "[Function: whoBigger]". Does anyone know why my function does not work?

Tags: javascript, function

```
//Program is intended to determine the bigger number
//Asks the user for two numbers
let numberOne = prompt("Give me a number");  
let numberTwo = prompt("Give me another number");  

//Checks which number is bigger  
function whoBigger(numberOne,numberTwo) {   
    if (numberOne > numberTwo) {  
        let whoBigger = "First number is bigger";  
    } else if (numberTwo > numberOne){  
        let whoBigger = "Second number is bigger";  
    } else{ 
        let whoBigger = "The numbers are equal";
    }

    console.log(whoBigger);

}

whoBigger(numberOne, numberTwo);
```

The code is meant to receive two numbers as an input and then determine which number is bigger.
I only get [Function: whoBigger]" as the output. Can anyone see where I went wrong?

Comment: I would recommend not using variables with the same name as a function. This will cause many headaches later on when you go to debug it

Answer (score 1):

`let` keyword is block-scoped so when you initialize a variable using `let` inside the if blocks, the variable is absent when you acesss them outside those blocks. Like in your case, there is no variable whoBigger when your code reaches the `console.log` line as it was present only in the if blocks. But a function with that name exists so, that gets logged.

```
function whoBigger(numberOne,numberTwo) {   
    // declaring the variable
    let whoBigger = ''

    if (numberOne>numberTwo) {  
         whoBigger="First number is bigger";  
    } else if (numberTwo>numberOne){  
         whoBigger="Second number is bigger";  
    } else{ 
         whoBigger="The numbers are equal";
    }

    console.log(whoBigger);

}
```

Note: Do not keep same names for functions and variables. Best practice is to keep all the names unique. In my answer, I have kept same names because the bug in your code was not related to the names.